# Building a GPT-3 Enabled Research Assistant with LangChain & Pinecone

Tags: csv, chatbot, gpt-3, langchain, pinecone

I would like a chatbot that can handle large CSV files and answer any questions about the data contained within them.

I have implemented Pinecone to store vector data and connected it with Langchain. However, the current setup is not providing accurate answers based on the given data. What could be the potential error in this configuration?

Comment: Please provide some samples of your implementation and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://www.mlq.ai/gpt-3-enabled-research-assistant-langchain-pinecone/                              instead of documents i loaded csv file using csvloader

Comment: Still, it's not clear at all what is your `query`, `docs` from the similarity search, and what you meant by not providing an accurate answer based on the given `docs`. You should provide some sample (minimal) of your version of implementation what you are expecting and what you are getting instead.